# State Mutation error is thrown when I try to modify a property in one array of objects based on another array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have 2 object arrays, one default and another is saved in local state.

```
Array 1
DefaultArray =  
[{type: typeA, isImportant: true, Content: ContentDefaultforA}, {type: typeB, isImportant: true, Content1: ContentDefaultforB1, Content2: ContentDefaultforB2}, {type: typeC, isImportant: false, Content: ContentDefaultforC}, {type: typeD, isImportant: false, Content: ContentDefaultforD}]
```

Value of

```
this.state.newArray = 
[{type: typeB, isImportant: true, Content1: ContentDefaultforB1, Content2: ContentDefaultforB2}, {type: typeA, isImportant: true, Content: ModifiedContentForA}, {type: typeD, Content: ModifiedCOntentForD, isImportant: true}, {type: typeC, isImportant: true, Content: ModifiedCOntentForC}]
```

I want to compare 2 arrays and change the isImportant property in this.state.newArray to whats in default array
So the result I want is

```
this.state.newArray = 
[{type: typeB, isImportant: true,, Content1: ContentDefaultforB1, isImportant: true, Content2: ContentDefaultforB2}, {type: typeA, isImportant: true, Content: ModifiedContentForA}, {type: typeD, Content: ModifiedCOntentForD, isImportant: false}, {type: typeC, isImportant: false, Content: ModifiedCOntentForC}]
```

I am doing this

```
let arrayCopy = [...this.state.newArray]
arrayCopy.forEach(item=>{
            let isImportant = defaultArray.filter(defaultItem=>defaultItem.type===item.type)[0].isImportant
            item.isImportant = isImportant
        })
```

This throws a state mutation

How can that be fixed? Also, is there an easier way to do it using lodash

Comment: You're (shallow-)copying the array, but you're not copying the object whose `.isImportant` property you mutate.

Comment: please make snippet of it using codesandbox